# How do I use findWithinHorizon to find a letter as many times as it appears in a string?

Tags: java

I'm trying to create a Java program that finds a specified letter from a scanner. Can I use findWithinHorizon to do this, and if so, how?

Comment: Have you tried writing any code yet for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If by scanner you mean **java.util.Scanner**

```
    public int fromScanner(Scanner scanner, String letter){
    scanner.useDelimiter(letter);
    int howMany = 0;
    while(scanner.hasNext()){
        scanner.next();
        ++howMany;
    }
    if(howMany>0)++howMany;
    return howMany;
}
```

*There are much better ways to count a letter*. Any hint of what you are doing?

**EDIT** here is actually using findWithinHorizon

```
 public int fromScanner2(Scanner scanner, String letter){ 
      int result = 0;
      String resultS = null;
      while( (resultS = scanner.findWithinHorizon(letter, 0)) !=null ){
           ++result;
      }
      return result;
 }
```

Now this method is a bit non-intuitive (at lest for me). When you use it and some occurrence is actually found, Scanner has internally an integer that keeps track of the position that last time was found. And on the next search it will use this postion to search *starting with it*

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
    Scanner sc = new Scanner("xxyyxxy");
    for (int n = 0;; n++) {
        String s = sc.findWithinHorizon("y", 0);
        if (s == null) {
            System.out.println(n);
            break;
        }
    }
```

output

3